# Call C++ Exported Function that returns a SqlConneciton object into C# Windows App

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, dllexport

Is there anyway to call an exported function in a DLL that could return a SqlConnection object to a C# project.  We are trying to have the DLL create a SqlConnection object that connects to the database with a secured password and then return the SqlConnection object.

Our company decided to use Application Role to grant the appropriate permissions the application needs.  The stored procedure requires the name of the app role and a password.  We do not want to store the password in the source code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Yes this is possible, just like loading any other external library.  You could also use sockets.  Do you have any code you have tried?

Comment: Why not use windows credentials in the database instead of sql credentials?  windows credentials is more secure because it does not use an unencrypted password, instead it uses an encrypted windows password.

Comment: Why would you ever want a connection to cross language boundaries...